# how to create a top down racing game like outrun for iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, xcode

I was thinking of making a top down racing game like the classic outrun or even the sega game road rush where the racetrack moves from the top of the screen towards the bottom when I realised that I couldn´t find any tutorials about this stuff. I mean tutorials about how to animate the racetrack to go from top to bottom. the player will see everything from behind the car

can anyone help me?

thanx!

Comment: You should probably have titled this something more direct like "Looking good tutorials for iPhone game development" but the honest answer here is that if you don't know where to get started, maybe you should start with something simpler.  Make a program which just uses menus or makes sound (make the startup page for your game!).  If you're already past this then I don't know where to go as I'm not an apple developer, just thought I try and help you get some help getting better help!

Comment: Actually im just looking for tutorials that who how to animate the track to go from top to down... I know the rest.. except that part. the player will see everything from behind the car

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this framework. It contains some good tutorials and is easy to use.

[Cocos 2D](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/)

I hope this help.

Comment: thanx for the input. :)  but i was thinking about using OPENGL or coreanimation for this.